# php Regular Expression match custom

Tags: php, regex

I'm not very good at regular expressions. Please help make the expression.

```
$subject = "action[attribute1=value1,attribute2=values,...]";
// format is ^word[str=str,...]$
```

I need to match "action", "attributes" and "values". thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, could you clarify a little bit more what you need the regular expression for?

Comment: #.*?(\\[.*?\\])#, but this returns only [...].
I have a function, which must allow user or group to continue to use another function:
    allow('restricted[group=admin]');
    // if ($user->group == admin) call_user_func('restricted');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find a match with regex pattern `\b(\w+)\[((?:(?<=[,\[])(?:\w+)=(?:[^,\]]+)[,\]]?)+)]`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

to get action name as **Group 1** and parameter list as **Group 2**.

---

In next step apply regex pattern `(?:^|(?<=,))(\w+)=([^,\]]+)(?=,|$)` to **Group 2** from above regex

[image: Regular expression visualization]

to get a list of attributes and associated values...

Comment: Nifty graphics -- how'd you generate them?

Comment: @EdCottrell :: https://www.debuggex.com/